# Using more than one provider in OAuth

Tags: php, oauth

Is there any problem, when using OAuth(v1 or v2) to have more than one provider?

Would this require the user to have two different logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a problem using two providers (ie: Using Twitter and Facebook), it's up to you on how both are handled on your side as the OAuth consumer. However, users will have to log in to both Facebook and Twitter (thus two logins/authentications) if they decide to use both.